# Link 2 modules generated by functors in 2 files

Tags: types, module, ocaml, functor

I have defined several modules as follows:

```
(* zone.ml *)
module ZoneFun (Prop : PROP) = (struct ... end: ZONE)

(* zones.ml *)
module ZonesFun (Zone : ZONE) = (struct ... end: ZONES)
```

where `PROP` is the interface of the module `Type` and some other modules.

```
(* calculate.ml *)
open Type
open Zone
open Zones

module ZoneType = ZoneFun(Type)
module ZonesType = ZonesFun(ZoneType)

let tries (x: ZonesType.t) : unit =
  Printf.printf "haha"

(* abs.ml *)
open Type
open Zone
open Zones
open Calculate

module ZoneType = ZoneFun(Type)
module ZonesType = ZonesFun(ZoneType)

module Abs = struct
  ...
  let abc (x: ZonesType.t) : unit =
    Calculate.tries x
  ...
end
```

Then the compilation gives me an error on the line of `Calculate.tries x` in `abs.ml`:

```
Error: This expression has type ZonesType.t = Zones.ZonesFun(ZoneType).t
       but an expression was expected of type
         Calculate.ZonesType.t = Zones.ZonesFun(Calculate.ZoneType).t
```

How could I tell the compilator that `Calculate.ZonesType.t` is actually same as `ZonesType.t` of `abs.ml`?

Comment: You can remove the type annotation and let ocaml infer the good type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you define the modules ZoneType and ZonesType twice. You should remove the second declaration as it hide the first one.
In your file abs.ml, remove the 2 lines `module Zone...`

Ocaml allows you to use the same name multiple times, but in that case, new declarations will hide the previous ones.

Comment: Sorry, actually in `abs.ml`, I have many other functions where I need to annotate `ZoneType` and `ZonesType`, so I must have the 2 lines `module Zone...` in `abs.ml`.

Comment: Yes, I understand but these modules are already created in calculate so `open Calculate` is all you need.